# Convert String to Date and compare dates

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a database where the date column is saved as type nvarchar and the date format is `dd/mm/yyyy` (British). I am trying to do a select query to search for data posted between two dates.

The query is:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
  WHERE CONVERT(datetime,postdate,103) BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

I have converted my field to datetime but whenever I try running my query I get an error

> java.lang.Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 
>   The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

When I run an isDate query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ISDATE(postdate)=0
```

A row with a date `18/02/2013` is shown. If I am not wrong this means that the **18** is being considered as a month.

How can I basically convert my field to a valid date and compare the dates?

Answer (score 3):

The first problem is you are storing dates in a string column. Why aren't you using `DATE` or `DATETIME`? If you're doing this to retain your d/m/y format, STOP doing that. Format is a presentation layer responsibility, and should not affect storage. Also, why are you using `NVARCHAR`? What kind of symbols do you anticipate in your date literals that would require Unicode?

Next is that you don't have proper validation, and bad data has ended up in your column. You can identify this bad data as follows:

```sql
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;

SELECT * FROM dbo.table
  WHERE ISDATE(postdate) = 0;
```

Now, fix that data, by either updating it when you know what it is, or setting those rows to `NULL`, until the query returns 0 rows.

*Note that you may have data like 11/13/2013, which obviously isn't in D/M/Y fomrat, and that if this is the case you could also have data that **seems** valid but did the user who entered 06/09/2013 mean June 9th or September 6th? How can you be sure?*

The safest way to prevent this problem from happening again tomorrow will likely be to add a new column, move the data over, drop the old column, and *stop* using strings at all layers.

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.table
  ADD d DATE;

UPDATE dbo.table 
  SET d = CONVERT(DATETIME, postdate, 103);

ALTER TABLE dbo.table
  DROP COLUMN postdate;

EXEC sp_rename N'dbo.table.d', N'postdate', N'COLUMN';
```

You may be able to do this inline without all this swapping as follows:

```sql
SET DATEFORMAT DMY; -- the key you missed in your attempt I think
ALTER TABLE dbo.table ALTER COLUMN postdate DATE;
```

If you can't fix the column itself, then at least consider adding a check constraint and some validation around this column so that bad data doesn't get back in there tomorrow. For example:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.table
  ADD CONSTRAINT prevent_bad_dates
  CHECK (CONVERT(DATE, postdate, 103) >= '19000101');
```

Your validation before even inserting, assuming you take a varchar parameter in to your stored procedure that performs the insert:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.whatever
  @postdate NVARCHAR(10), -- assuming here
  @other_params...
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  SET DATEFORMAT DMY;

  IF ISDATE(@postdate) = 0
  BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Incorrect format for date: %s.', 11, 1, @postdate);
    RETURN;
  END

  ... perform insert...
END
```

This *still* won't help you comprehend whether a user who entered `06/09/2013` meant June 9th or September 6th. So I urge you to take that freehand ad hoc entry away from your users and force them to use a calendar control or date picker or something, that way *you* can control the format entirely. If you need to send string literals to SQL Server, the safest format is going to be `YYYYMMDD`. Also you should be aware of the potential issues with using `BETWEEN` instead of an open-ended range. Please read the following posts:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Answer (score -1):

when you retrieve the date from the database you get date in java.sql.date format!

you now need to convert it into java.util.date!

it can be done by using the following code

```
java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date(SQLDate.getTime());
```

try it and it will be done!!

Comment: This is not a java problem. It's purely SQL. Java only throws the exception